# Placing grid items without using template areas

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a container with 4 elements which I would like to lay out like this:

```
┌───┬───┐
│ a │ c │
╞═══╪═══╡
│ b │ d │
└───┴───┘
```

The HTML is something like the following:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="a">

    </div>
    <div id="b">

    </div>
    <div id="c">

    </div>
    <div id="d">

    </div>
</div>
```

Note that the elements go down first, then across.

I know I can achieve this layout using `grid-template-areas` for the container and `grid-area` for the inner elements. However, this involves naming all four of these elements individually.

Is there a way of achieving the same layout without individually naming these elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `grid-auto-flow: column` to your grid container. No need for `grid-template-areas`.

This property controls the directional flow of grid items. The default value is `row`.

```css
#container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 50px;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 50px;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

/* non-essential demo styles */
#container > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="a">a</div>
  <div id="b">b</div>
  <div id="c">c</div>
  <div id="d">e</div>
</div>
```

> [§ 7.7. Automatic Placement: the `grid-auto-flow`
>   property](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-auto-flow-property)
>
> [This property] controls how the auto-placement algorithm works,
>   specifying exactly how auto-placed items get flowed into the grid.
>
> ***`row`***
>
> The auto-placement algorithm places items by filling each row in turn,
>   adding new rows as necessary. If neither `row` nor `column` is
>   provided, row is assumed.
>
> ***`column`***
>
> The auto-placement algorithm places items by filling each column in
>   turn, adding new columns as necessary.

Comment: Perfect. That’s exactly what I was looking for. I found that the combination of `grid-template-rows` and `grid-auto-flow: column` did the trick. There is much I need to learn about CSS grids. Thanks.